# is there a way to combine two foreach loops in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

right now I can acces my data with foreach loops i have the following two:

```
@foreach($data->posts as $post)
```

and

```
@foreach($data->terms as $term)
```

I am looking for a way to get both data ($post and $term) out of one foreach loop instead of having to loop through both:

```
@foreach($data->posts as $post) 
    @foreach($data->terms as $term)

 @if($post->name == $term->name) 

etc
```

Comment: That's a strange thing, how would that work exactly according to you?

Comment: why do you want to do that? if you are sure that both of the two arrays have the same length so you can loop over one array and access the other one using the loop index

Comment: @hassan i want to put them in a table, but they dont have the same length which makes it a bit annoying

Comment: you should merge the data how you want either in your controller or models

Comment: are the terms related to the posts?

Comment: @hassan they are both different arrays within the $data

Comment: It would really help if you show us samples of the contents of the arrays and the expected result you want the code to create. We are working a bit blind.

Comment: Please provide sample of both array.